# How much narrower does the question about boat docks need to be to in order to be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/when-would-docks-on-chatfield-reservoir-be-least-busy-with-boaters-putting-in-an) about boat docks was closed as too broad. [This is the original version](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/revisions/53c9a55a-1ceb-43f9-8f05-3928aca63662/view-source) before it was closed or edited.

What needs to be added to make it narrow enough to be reopened?

- Season of the year?
- Particular dock?
- Day or night?

It has already been narrowed to just docks and **just one lake**, how **much narrower does it need to be?**

Comment: I know so little about boating that I can't attempt to edit your question. But it I were to edit it, it would be something like: For a small (medium, large) freshwater lake or a reservoir in California (?) that is popular with (fishermen, boaters), what is likely to be the best time to go magnet fishing from the pier without disturbing fishermen or boaters?  I'd add the type of fish found there, because that might make a diference when they are biting.

Comment: Continued: I should think experienced fisherpeople or boaters could answer the question as phrased in my comment above, even if the answer is mid-day, mid-week on a cold, rainy day. (If anything, the Q is now too narrow.)

Answer (score 2):

First I want to commend you for all the work you are doing in support of TGO, writing fresh question and good answers is hard work.

The question was closed when I first saw it, and I have not voted to re-open since it was edited.

I left this comment before it was edited [When would docks on Chatfield Reservoir be least busy with boaters putting in and taking out?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/when-would-docks-on-chatfield-reservoir-be-least-busy-with-boaters-putting-in-an#comment59091_22305)

> The most correct answer is 3AM on a dark and stormy night. Obviously not the best answer, I think this should stay closed.as by the time you narrow it to be helpful it is going to be more localized then the OP is aiming for

I think in it's current state it would not have been closed.

The question becomes, "why is not being re-opened?" or from my perspective why am I not voting to re-open it?

It is really not that good of a question.  I would not give it an upvote, so I am not giving it a re-open vote.

Personally I think you are starting to drift towards volume of questions, and away from quality of questions. At least your more recent questions have not been as good as your older questions.

I respect you, and I appreciate all of your hard work.  I hope you will keep writing new questions.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Presumably from one of the two people voting to re-open the question, and wishing everyone would vote the same as them?

Comment: There are tow things that frustrate me about this, 1 this is one the questions where I actually care about the answer as opposed to say seal slapping and 2 I answer other peoples silly literal RTFM questions https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22339/what-is-the-v-notch-on-top-of-the-clickup-climbing-belay-device-for all of the time and it would nice if other people would answer my questions

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I am sorry, my impression was that it was not a personal question. There is a comment suggestion at least one person has an answer I will cast an open vote.

Comment: James, thank you for this answer. I think it's really nicely worded, and expresses your honest feelings while still encouraging the OP. It took a level of courage and a lot of thought! It reflects my feelings exactly, and probably those of other community members. I upvoted, and can only make assumptions about the downvote. Hopefully it wasn't personal.